# Extjs DomQuery How To Traverse Dom elements

Tags: dom, extjs, xml-parsing

I'm just a beginner. thanks for your understanding.

Lets say I have an xml file like the following. And I want to get Student tags which include Name tags valued "aaa".

```
<Students>
      <Student>
        <Name> aaa </Name>
        <Surname> bbb </Surname>
        ...
      </Student>
      <Student>
        <Name> ccc </Name>
        <Surname> ddd </Surname>
        ...
      </Student>
      ...
    </students>
```

I tried this,

```
Ext.DomQuery.select('Students/Student/Name:nodeValue(aaa)', xmlDoc)
```

but, this gives only Name nodes nut Student nodes.

I want to be able to filter nodes based on their children nodes' values.

I hope someone helps me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can to get children elements and then loop over them and get their parents. But, in your case, you can use `:contains` pseudoclass like here: http://jsfiddle.net/guyfawkes/caxvN/